# Hacer que corra un query UPDATE en Microsoft access en un formulario?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero hacer que se pueda cambiar masivamente una tabla usando un query UPDATE dentro de una forma de Access, el problema es que siempre tira errores diferentes y no lo hace

Esta es mi forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El nombre del textbox de arriba es Oldval y el de abajo se llama Newval

Este es el codigo que tengo al presionar el boton

```
Dim SQL As String
Dim Viejo As Double
Dim Nuevo As Double

Oldval.SetFocus
Newval.SetFocus

Viejo = Me.Oldval.Value
Nuevo = Me.Newval.Value
 
SQL = "UPDATE Inventario" & _
      "SET Inventario.Valor_del_dolar = 'Nuevo'" & _
      "WHERE Inventario.Valor_del_dolar = 'Viejo'"
 
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Esta es la estructura de mi tabla, intento cambiar valor_del_dolar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los errores varian de no tener focus a decir que tengo un error ortografico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo varios inconvenientes en tu código:

- Llamas al método SetFocus de los edits, cosa que no creo que sea necesaria.
- No concatenas los valores, sino que pasas las cadenas `'nuevo'` y `'viejo'` como parte del SQL
- Al concatenar con las líneas siguientes, hacen falta espacios. La cadena resultante queda, por ejemplo, así: `'UPDATE InventarioSET...'`, lo cual va a dar un error.

Adicional a esto, yo suelo utilizar conversiones explícitas (de hecho, no sé si tu código se ejecuta sin problemas al no utilizarlas).

Ajusta el código de esta forma:

```
Dim SQL As String
Dim Viejo As Double
Dim Nuevo As Double

Viejo = CDbl(Me.Oldval.Value)
Nuevo = CDbl(Me.Newval.Value)
 
SQL = "UPDATE Inventario" & _
      " SET Inventario.Valor_del_dolar = " & CStr(Nuevo) & _
      " WHERE Inventario.Valor_del_dolar = " & CStr(Viejo)
 
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```